# Strava GPX upload with python module requests is giving a ValueError - why?

Tags: python-requests, strava

I don't understand why this ValueError occurs?

- Post request

```
import requests

headers = {'authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}
files = [{'file': open('../poc_data/Sport-sessions/GPS-data/2012-08-09_05-32-43-UTC_55d566fa93bc7d9d1757b8e0.gpx', 'rb')}, {'data_type': 'gpx'}, {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}]

r = requests.post('https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads', headers=headers, files=files)
```

- Error traceback

  *Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/projekte/11_github/poc_runtastic/poc_code/strava_upload_activities.py", line 19, in <module>
  r = requests.post('https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads', headers=headers, files=files)
  File "E:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 117, in post
  return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
  return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File "E:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 528, in request

  prep = self.prepare_request(req)

  File "E:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in prepare_request

  p.prepare(

  File "E:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 319, in prepare

  self.prepare_body(data, files, json)

  File "E:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 512, in prepare_body

  (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)

  File "E:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 141, in

  _encode_files

  for (k, v) in files:*

  **ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that effect regards to the API-design: it is expecting one explicit dictionary named **headers** and one named **params**.
In my given example above I sent only one (headers) and that explains the ValueError.

This code works:

```
import requests


files = {
    'file': open('../poc_data/Sport-sessions/GPS-data/2012-08-09_05-32-43-UTC_55d566fa93bc7d9d1757b8e0.gpx', 'rb')
}
headers = {
    'authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
}
params = {
    'data_type': 'gpx'
}
url = 'https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads'


r = requests.post(files=files, headers=headers, params=params, url=url)
```